# How to get discount amount for each item from order id / item id

Tags: magento2, sales-order, discount, shipment

How can I get the discount amount for each item in an order?
using its `order id`/`item id`.

I am not able to retrieve `the discount amount` from its `order id`/`item id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `getDiscountAmount()` method

```
$orderid=1001;
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);
$order->getDiscountAmount(); /* amount */
$order->getDiscountDescription(); /* get description */
$order->getDiscountTaxCompensationAmount();
```